# Find string in a file to another file

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to find keywords in FILE2 to each column of FILE1 and print `<BLANK>` if keywords in `FILE2` is not in `FILE1` regardless of the separators.

#### FILE1

```
XYZ=TRS-000|XYZ=TWR-000|UJU=909|GFT=879|JKP=908
XYZ=TRS-000|XYZ=TWR-000|GFT=879|JKP=908
```

#### FILE2

```
TRS-0
TWR
UJU
GFT-8
```

#### OUTPUT

```
XYZ=TRS-000|XYZ=TWR-000|UJU=909|GFT=879
XYZ=TRS-000|XYZ=TWR-000||GFT=879
```

---

#### SCRIPT so far

(This script finds exact match in FILE2 to FILE1 columns (with = as separator). I can't figure out how to do: if a string from FILE2 **contained** in a column in FILE1. )

```
BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}
NR==FNR{a[++i]=$1;next}
{
  d=""
  delete b
  for(j=1;j<=NF;j++){
    split($j,c,"-")
    b[c[1]]=$j;
  }
  for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
  d=d (d==""?"":OFS) (a[j] in b?b[a[j]]:"")
  }
  print d
}
```

`

Comment: What exactly is your question, what is the problem?

Comment: @ultramini: In your sample output, where is *<BLANK>* printed????

Comment: <BLANK> will be printed if a keyword in FILE2 is not in FILE1. In my sample output here: `XYZ=TRS-000|XYZ=TWR-000|<BLANK>|GFT=879` a blank is printed because it did not find **UJU** keyword in it (FILE1 second line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
NR==FNR { sub(/[^[:alpha:]].*/,""); keys[++numKeys]=$0; next }
{
    delete key2val
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
            key = keys[keyNr]
            if ( $i ~ ("="key"-|^"key"=") ) {
                key2val[key] = $i
            }
        }
    }
    for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        printf "%s%s", key2val[key], (keyNr<numKeys?OFS:ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
XYZ=TRS-000|XYZ=TWR-000|UJU=909|GFT=879
XYZ=TRS-000|XYZ=TWR-000||GFT=879
```

Comment: I also dragging my brain about this task, wondering how optimally deal with an array offset

Comment: How if I disregard the "=" and "-" because I might add keywords in file2 that contains "-" or "=" (eg TRS-0).

Comment: It's extremely important for the example you provide to truly reflect your real input. If that could change, what else might change? Take some time to really **THINK** about your real problem and then edit your question to show sample input and expected output that truly captures it.

Comment: OK, I've added `sub(/[^[:alpha:]].*/,"");` to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample input, there are two patterns for determining the keyword after the split. This solution sets index `i` accordingly.

```
BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"}

NR==FNR {a[$1]=NR; cols=NR; next}

{
    delete out
    for (f=1;f<=NF;++f) {
        i = ($f ~ /^.*=.*-.*$/) ? 2 : 1
        split($f, b, /[=-]/)
        if (b[i] in a) {
            out[a[b[i]]] = $f
        }
    }
    printf "%s", out[1]
    for (j=2; j<=cols; ++j) {
        printf "%s%s", OFS, out[j]
    }
    print ""
}


$ cat file1
XYZ=TRS-000|XYZ=TWR-000|UJU=909|GFT=879|JKP=908
XYZ=TRS-000|XYZ=TWR-000|GFT=879|JKP=908

$ cat file2
TRS
TWR
UJU
GFT

$ awk -f utl.awk file2 file1
XYZ=TRS-000|XYZ=TWR-000|UJU=909|GFT=879
XYZ=TRS-000|XYZ=TWR-000||GFT=879
```

Comment: This is great. But can I pattern the column format based on file2? like in line 2 (output) **XYZ=TRS-000|XYZ=TWR-000|<blank>|GFT=879** <blank >must be in column 3 since *UJU* is in 3rd line in file2.

Comment: Okay, see edit. Now uses the ordering in file2 to determine the column order of the output.